# How do I create a nested function in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, scope, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I would like to create a function in PL/pgSQL with a couple of nested (or inner) functions within it.  This way I can break the problem down into smaller pieces but not have my smaller pieces accessible outside of this function.

Is it possible to do this in PL/pgSQL? If so, how?

Comment: Why would you do that? Seems impractical to me. You can break the problem into smaller pieces without many functions or if you really need it - adjust privileges on them.

Comment: @KamilGosciminski - you mentioned that you "can break the problem into smaller pieces without many functions" - curious to know how you might go about that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nested functions are not supported by PLpgSQL. The emulation has not any sense and it is non-productive (with possible negative performance impacts).

Comment: At first glance the emulation described by kiwi worked.  I tested it on smaller datasets and it looked good.  When working with larger datesets, however, it always failed with very strange locking errors.  I think anyone reading this would be best served by not trying to force nested functions to work in a PL/pgSQL.

Comment: @GregoryArenius: I did some playing with that example, it creates/replaces the function "inner" (in same scope as "outer" function) every time the function "outer" is called, hence weird errors.  It isn't an "inner function" at all, and it it has no access to the inner scope of "outer" either.

Comment: "Inner function" often means in programming languages you will want to access the outer function's variables from the inner function. This won't work in apteryx' example.

Answer (score 15):

Try it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION outer() RETURNS void AS $outer$
DECLARE s text;
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inner() RETURNS text AS $inner$
  BEGIN
    RETURN 'inner';
  END;
  $inner$ language plpgsql;

  SELECT inner() INTO s;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', s;

  DROP FUNCTION inner();
END;
$outer$ language plpgsql;
```

In postgres 9.5 `SELECT outer();` outputs

```
 psql:/vagrant/f.sql:14: NOTICE:  inner
```

EDIT: if you don't drop the inner 
function at the end of the outer function it will remain visible to the rest of the database.

Comment: A couple things to point out to anyone else trying this: You can't just use `AS $$` for both the inner and the outer function. Also, if your function has arguments you must pass the types when you drop that function.  And you can't call your functions in the `DECLARE` portion of the outer function because they haven't been created yet.  Just create the variable and assign a value to it after the creation of the nested functions.

Comment: @Gregory: One more important point: If two concurrent transactions try to call this function, the second one will block on the inner `CREATE` until the first one commits, due to the database's uniqueness constraint on function names. You can work around this by putting the inner function in your session's temp schema, i.e. by using `CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.inner()`. The added benefit is that the inner functions are never externally visible, and are automatically cleaned up after your session.

Comment: @Gregory: By the way, `DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END` blocks can be nested, so you can do your declarations after the inner function is created

Comment: Creating a new (inner) function on each (outer) function call seems to be wasteful.